# how to find inverse of matrix of big length in java?

Tags: java

iam working in searchable encryption algorithm that using bloom filter data structure and for encrypting this bloom filter should use matrix of big length the same length of bloom filter in encryption  but when i used the following matrix. it run only in maximum length[10][10].can anyone help me to develop this implemetation to make it run in big length.

```
public class Matrix {
   //double[][] value1={{0,92,0.15,0.7},{0.33,1,0.3},{0.24,0.39,0.03}};
    //double [][] value2={{0.57,0.7,0.87},{0.77,0.51,0.83},{0.27,0,0.87}};
    //int []s={1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1};

    public int columns;
    public int rows;
    public double[][] matrix;

    public Matrix(double[][] matr) {
        this.matrix = matr;
        this.rows = matr.length;
        this.columns = matr[0].length;
    }

    public Matrix(int a, int b) {
        this.rows = a;
        this.columns = b;
        matrix = new double[rows][columns];
    }
    public int size(){
        return columns;
    }
    //}
   // Matrix M1=new Matrix(value1);
    //Matrix M2=new Matrix(value2);

    public static Matrix cofactor(Matrix M) {
        Matrix cofactorOfM = new Matrix(M.getNrows(),M.getNcols());
        for (int i = 0; i < M.getNrows(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < M.getNcols(); j++) {
                cofactorOfM.setValueAt(i, j, changeSign(i) * changeSign(j) * determinant(createSubMatrix(M, i, j)));
            }
        }
        return cofactorOfM;
    }

    public static Matrix transpose(Matrix M) {
        Matrix transposedMatrix = new Matrix(M.getNrows(), M.getNcols());
        for (int i = 0; i < M.getNrows(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < M.getNcols(); j++) {
                transposedMatrix.setValueAt(j, i, M.getValueAt(i, j));
            }
        }
        return transposedMatrix;
    }

    public static double determinant(Matrix M)  {

        if(M.size()==1){
           return M.getValueAt(0, 0);
        }
        if(M.size()==2){
            return(M.getValueAt(0, 0)*(M.getValueAt(1, 1)))-((M.getValueAt(0, 1)*(M.getValueAt(1, 0))));
        }

        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < M.getNcols(); i++) {
            sum += changeSign(i) * M.getValueAt(0, i) * determinant(createSubMatrix(M, 0, i));

        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static Matrix createSubMatrix(Matrix M, int excluding_row, int excluding_col) {
        Matrix mat = new Matrix(M.getNrows()-1,M.getNcols()-1);

        int r = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < M.getNrows(); i++) {
            if (i == excluding_row) {
                continue;
            }
            r++;
            int c = -1;
            for (int j = 0; j <M.getNcols(); j++) {
                if (j == excluding_col) {
                    continue;
                }
                mat.setValueAt(r, ++c, M.getValueAt(i, j));
            }
        }
        return mat;
    }

    public static Matrix inverse(Matrix M) {
        return (transpose(cofactor(M)).multiplyByConstant(1.0 / determinant(M)));
    }

    public static int changeSign(int i) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public double getValueAt(int i, int j) {
        return this.matrix[i][j];
    }

    public void setValueAt(int i, int j, double val) {
        this.matrix[i][j] = val;
    }

    public Matrix multiplyByConstant(double constant) {
        Matrix mat = new Matrix(rows, columns);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                mat.setValueAt(i, j, matrix[i][j] * constant);
            }
        }
        return mat;

    }
    public int getNrows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public void setNrows(int nrows) {
        this.rows = nrows;
    }

    public int getNcols() {
        return columns;
    }

    public void setNcols(int ncols) {
        this.columns = ncols;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it only runs “in a maximum length[10][10]”?  Is it hitting a stack recursion limit?  Not running within a reasonable time limit?  Giving erroneous output due to numerical limits?

Comment: @AJNeufeld when compute inverse of matrix of big length say 15 its running take a lot of time and doesnot appear any result.

Comment: So ... basically, you have bugs in your code, and you want someone to find the bugs for you.  Correct?   If so then, you need to provide a proper MCVE.

Comment: Since the code you posted works (for small matrices), this question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow.  It might be more appropriate to post it on another stack exchange site, where you can get feedback on the algorithm ... which suffers from a complexity breakdown.

Comment: Your `determinant()` function is at least O(N!) complexity.  And since your `cofactor()` function calls `determinant()` N^2 times, it gives your inverse function O(N! * N^2) complexity.  The inverse of a 15x15 matrix will take 81,081,000 times longer than a 10x10 matrix to compute.  You need to look into other algorithms for inverting a matrix.  See also: [Don't invert that matrix](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/).

Comment: If you **really need efficient variants** of such operations, you're almost ever better off using an optimized library instead of implementing it by yourself. Especially for numeric matrix operations. There are libraries that use extremely optimized cutting edge algorithms and work near to your hardware which boosts a lot.